# Does Spark Dataframe have an equivalent option of Panda's merge indicator?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The python Pandas library contains the following function :

```
DataFrame.merge(right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False,
                right_index=False, sort=False, suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True,
                indicator=False)
```

The indicator field combined with Panda's value_counts() function can be used to quickly determine how well a join performed.

Example:

```
In [48]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1], 'col_left':['a', 'b']})

In [49]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 2],'col_right':[2, 2, 2]})

In [50]: pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col1', how='outer', indicator=True)
Out[50]: 
   col1 col_left  col_right      _merge
0     0        a        NaN   left_only
1     1        b        2.0        both
2     2      NaN        2.0  right_only
3     2      NaN        2.0  right_only
```

What is the best way to check the performance of a join within a Spark Dataframe?

A custom function was provided in 1 of the answers: It does not yet give the correct results but it would be great if it would:

```
ASchema = StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType(),nullable=False),
                 StructField('name', StringType(),nullable=False)])
BSchema = StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType(),nullable=False),
                 StructField('role', StringType(),nullable=False)])
AData = sc.parallelize ([ Row(1,'michel'), Row(2,'diederik'), Row(3,'rok'), Row(4,'piet')])
BData = sc.parallelize ([ Row(1,'engineer'), Row(2,'lead'), Row(3,'scientist'), Row(5,'manager')])
ADF = hc.createDataFrame(AData,ASchema)
BDF = hc.createDataFrame(BData,BSchema)
DFJOIN = ADF.join(BDF, ADF['id'] == BDF['id'], "outer")
DFJOIN.show()

Input:
+----+--------+----+---------+
|  id|    name|  id|     role|
+----+--------+----+---------+
|   1|  michel|   1| engineer|
|   2|diederik|   2|     lead|
|   3|     rok|   3|scientist|
|   4|    piet|null|     null|
|null|    null|   5|  manager|
+----+--------+----+---------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
DFJOINMERGE = DFJOIN.withColumn("_merge", when(ADF["id"].isNull(), "right_only").when(BDF["id"].isNull(), "left_only").otherwise("both"))\
  .withColumn("id", coalesce(ADF["id"], BDF["id"]))\
   .drop(ADF["id"])\
   .drop(BDF["id"])
DFJOINMERGE.show()

Output
+---+--------+---+---------+------+
| id|    name| id|     role|_merge|
+---+--------+---+---------+------+
|  1|  michel|  1| engineer|  both|
|  2|diederik|  2|     lead|  both|
|  3|     rok|  3|scientist|  both|
|  4|    piet|  4|     null|  both|
|  5|    null|  5|  manager|  both|
+---+--------+---+---------+------+

 ==> I would expect id 4 to be left, and id 5 to be right.

Changing join to "left":


Input:
+---+--------+----+---------+
| id|    name|  id|     role|
+---+--------+----+---------+
|  1|  michel|   1| engineer|
|  2|diederik|   2|     lead|
|  3|     rok|   3|scientist|
|  4|    piet|null|     null|
+---+--------+----+---------+

Output
+---+--------+---+---------+------+
| id|    name| id|     role|_merge|
+---+--------+---+---------+------+
|  1|  michel|  1| engineer|  both|
|  2|diederik|  2|     lead|  both|
|  3|     rok|  3|scientist|  both|
|  4|    piet|  4|     null|  both|
+---+--------+---+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> sdf1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df1)
>>> sdf2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df2)
>>> sdf = sdf1.join(sdf2, sdf1["col1"] == sdf2["col1"], "outer")
>>> sdf.withColumn("_merge", when(sdf1["col1"].isNull(), "right_only").when(sdf2["col1"].isNull(), "left_only").otherwise("both"))\
...  .withColumn("col1", coalesce(sdf1["col1"], sdf2["col1"]))\
...   .drop(sdf1["col1"])\
...   .drop(sdf2["col1"])
```

Comment: thanks alot. I tested it and it seems both each time, i will put the test code in the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Both examples work fine for me.

Comment: Interesting, Which spark and python version do you use? We use Spark 1.6 and Python 2,7 using Jupyter notebook. If you run the exact same example code it could be some version issue .

Comment: 1.6.2 / Python 3.5

Comment: in python 3 got same result however got it working by changing some fields within your answer . will put the result in the question

Comment: I got error on dataframe with only column `col`, all rows are labeled as `right_only`. I renamed the column explicitly as `col`, `col2` to avoid confusing spark and it works.

Answer (score 6):

Altered LostInOverflow 's answer and got this working:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

ASchema = StructType([StructField('ida', IntegerType(),nullable=False),
                 StructField('name', StringType(),nullable=False)])
BSchema = StructType([StructField('idb', IntegerType(),nullable=False),
                 StructField('role', StringType(),nullable=False)])
AData = sc.parallelize ([ Row(1,'michel'), Row(2,'diederik'), Row(3,'rok'), Row(4,'piet')])
BData = sc.parallelize ([ Row(1,'engineer'), Row(2,'lead'), Row(3,'scientist'), Row(5,'manager')])
ADF = hc.createDataFrame(AData,ASchema)
BDF = hc.createDataFrame(BData,BSchema)
DFJOIN = ADF.join(BDF, ADF['ida'] == BDF['idb'], "outer")
DFJOIN.show()


+----+--------+----+---------+
| ida|    name| idb|     role|
+----+--------+----+---------+
|   1|  michel|   1| engineer|
|   2|diederik|   2|     lead|
|   3|     rok|   3|scientist|
|   4|    piet|null|     null|
|null|    null|   5|  manager|
+----+--------+----+---------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
DFJOINMERGE = DFJOIN.withColumn("_merge", when(DFJOIN["ida"].isNull(), "right_only").when(DFJOIN["idb"].isNull(), "left_only").otherwise("both"))\
  .withColumn("id", coalesce(ADF["ida"], BDF["idb"]))\
   .drop(DFJOIN["ida"])\
   .drop(DFJOIN["idb"])
#DFJOINMERGE.show()
DFJOINMERGE.groupBy("_merge").count().show()

+----------+-----+
|    _merge|count|
+----------+-----+
|right_only|    1|
| left_only|    1|
|      both|    3|
+----------+-----+
```