# How to join two dataframes with option as in Pandas

Tags: join, pyspark

My goal is to translate this below join into PySpark

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, 
                        left_on=['user','timestamp1'], 
                        right_on=['user','timestamp2'],
                       how='left')
```

I did this but it isn't the desirable result

```
merged_df = df1.join(df2, 
                     (df1.user==df2.user) & (df1.timestamp1==df2.timestamp2), 
                     how='left')
```

Comment: would help if u could provide reproducible examples of your data and required output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark join multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041710/pyspark-join-multiple-conditions)

Comment: I'm looking for something like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721194/does-spark-dataframe-have-an-equivalent-option-of-pandas-merge-indicator